# Exclude login page from custom maintenance code

Tags: login

I have a custom code to get into maintenance mode which excludes from it anyone who is logged in or is in the login page, with this if statement:

```
   if (
     !is_user_logged_in() && 
     !is_admin() && 
     !in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'))
   )
```

The problem I have is that I've set a custom URL to get to the login page for security reasons. So I write www.example.com/custom instead of www.example.com/wp-admin or www.example.com/wp-login.

That's why I need to add some code to the above if statement to detect when the user is on the custom URL login page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a somewhat similar requirement to you. Currently I am using the below to test for the correct scenario:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() == true  || 
     in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php')) || 
     strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') != 0)
```

This doesn't *detect* if you have changed the login URLs but you could define Globals or plugin variables to specify 'wp-login.php' and 'wp-admin' strings so that they can be more conveniently controlled, albeit manually.

I'm not convinced its the neatest solution but its the only one I have at the moment and seems to do what I need. Perhaps it helps?